# How to read modifier child elements in custom view?

Tags: swift, swiftui

How can I read the value of modifier used in child elements in my custom view, I want to achieve the effect like TabView ?

```swift
struct TabItem: View {
    var body: some View {
        TabView {
            View1()
                .tabItem {
                    Label("Menu", systemImage: "list.dash")
                }


            View2()
                .tabItem {
                    Label("Order", systemImage: "square.and.pencil")
                }
        }
    }
}
```

I want the parent view, i.e. my CustomView, to read whether the child element has a custom modifier, e.g. .inCustomView, and read the content from it and create a button or something else based on it, just like in the case of e.g. TabView

Comment: Do you want to read an existing view modifier or your own view modifier? Whether you control the view modifier matters a lot.

Comment: @Sweeper

My own modifier, I want it to be possible to place a View in it, e.g. Label, as in the case of tabItem

`func tabItem<V>(@ViewBuilder _ label: () -> V) -> some View where V : View`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You would need to use some underscore-prefixed (meaning they are unstable) APIs to read the views that are in a `ViewBuilder`. Then you can read a view trait using your own trait key, again using underscore-prefixed APIs. The trait can store an `AnyView` representing the view passed to your custom modifier.

To extracting the views from a `ViewBuilder`, you can use the Swift Package [View Extractor](https://github.com/GeorgeElsham/ViewExtractor). You can look at how they do this - it's not a lot of code.

As an example, let's create a `VStack` that allows you to add buttons at the bottom of its subviews by using a custom modifier, `vstackButtonLabel`. Users can use this to specify the view they want for the button's label.

```
struct VStackWithButtons<Content: View>: View {
    @ViewBuilder let content: () -> Content
    
    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            content()
            HStack {
                ExtractMulti(content) { views in
                    // "views" is a RandomAccessCollection
                    ForEach(views) { view in
                        // You can also access "view.id" here if needed 
                        if let buttonLabel = view[VStackButtonLabelTrait.self] {
                            Button {
                                print("Do something")
                            } label: {
                                buttonLabel
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

`VStackButtonLabelTrait` is a `_ViewTraitKey`:

```
struct VStackButtonLabelTrait: _ViewTraitKey {
    static let defaultValue: AnyView? = nil
}

extension View {
    func vstackButtonLabel<Content: View>(@ViewBuilder content: () -> Content) -> some View {
        _trait(VStackButtonLabelTrait.self, AnyView(content()))
    }
}
```

Example usage:

```
VStackWithButtons {
    Text("This has no buttons")
    
    Text("This has a button")
        .vstackButtonLabel {
            Label("Foo", systemImage: "globe")
        }
    
    Text("This also has a button")
        .vstackButtonLabel {
            Label("Bar", systemImage: "rectangle")
        }
}
```

Result:

[image]

As another example, here is a very simple "tab view" (if you can even call it that) that allows you to select tabs using a picker.

```
struct ContentView: View {
    @State var selectedTab = 0
    var body: some View {
        CustomTabView(selectedTab: $selectedTab) {
            Text("Tab 1")
                .id(0)
            
            Text("Tab 2")
                .id(1)
                .customTabItem {
                    Label("Foo", systemImage: "globe")
                }
            
            Text("Tab 3")
                .id(2)
                .customTabItem {
                    Label("Bar", systemImage: "rectangle")
                }
        }
    }
}

struct CustomTabView<Content: View, Selection: Hashable>: View {
    
    @Binding var selectedTab: Selection
    
    @ViewBuilder let content: () -> Content
    
    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            ExtractMulti(content) { views in
                ForEach(views) { view in
                    if view.id(as: Selection.self) == selectedTab {
                        view
                    }
                }
            }
            Picker("Pick", selection: $selectedTab) {
                ExtractMulti(content) { views in
                    ForEach(views) { view in
                        if let id = view.id(as: Selection.self) {
                            if let label = view[CustomTabItemTrait.self] {
                                label.tag(id)
                            } else {
                                Text("Unnamed").tag(id)
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}

extension View {
    func customTabItem<Content: View>(@ViewBuilder content: () -> Content) -> some View {
        _trait(CustomTabItemTrait.self, AnyView(content()))
    }
}

struct CustomTabItemTrait: _ViewTraitKey {
    static let defaultValue: AnyView? = nil
}
```

Comment: Perfect, just what I needed and what I wanted to achieve

Comment: I found only one problem when we use inbuilt view like Text or Button it works but when custome e.g. TestView doesn't, I'm talking about the "Custom TabView" example

Comment: @GetReady What does `TestView`'s body contain? And are you using it as one of the tabs, or are you using it in `customTabItem`? `Picker` only supports a very limited set of things, so it is natural that you cannot pass *any* view into `customTabItem` and have it appear in the `Picker`. But you should be able to apply `customTabItem` to any view.

Comment: `struct TestView: View { var body: some View { Text("Test View") } }
`
`CustomTabView(selectedTab: $selectedTab) { TestView().id(0).customTabItem { Label("Test", systemImage: "rectangle") }`

@Sweeper

Comment: @GetReady That code works on my machine. Please explain what you mean by "doesn't work". What unexpected thing happened when you run the app?

Comment: I'm very sorry for the misunderstanding, it doesn't work, but only in the preview, I just checked. A bit irritating because it makes designing difficult, but generally it works @Sweeper

Answer (score -1):

To achieve the effect you want, where the parent view, CustomView, can read the value of a modifier used in its child elements, you can use the following approach:

1. Create a custom TabItem modifier:

```
struct CustomTabItem<Content: View>: ViewModifier {
    let content: Content

    func body(content: Content) -> some View {
        content
            .background(
                GeometryReader { geometry in
                    Color.clear.preference(key: CustomTabItemPreferenceKey.self, value: geometry.size)
                }
            )
    }
}

extension View {
    func customTabItem<Content: View>(@ViewBuilder content: () -> Content) -> some View {
        modifier(CustomTabItem(content: content()))
    }
}

struct CustomTabItemPreferenceKey: PreferenceKey {
    static var defaultValue: CGSize = .zero

    static func reduce(value: inout CGSize, nextValue: () -> CGSize) {
        value = nextValue()
    }
}
```

2. In your CustomView, add a preference reader to read the size of the custom tab item:

```
struct CustomView: View {
    @Preference var customTabItemSize: CGSize?

    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            if let customTabItemSize = customTabItemSize {
                // Create a button or something else based on the size of the custom tab item
                Button(action: {}) {
                    Text("Custom Tab Item")
                }
                .frame(width: customTabItemSize.width, height: customTabItemSize.height)
            }

            // Your other content
        }
    }
}
```

3. In your child view, use the `customTabItem` modifier to apply the custom modifier to the tab item:

```
struct View1: View {
    var body: some View {
        Text("View 1")
            .customTabItem {
                Label("Menu", systemImage: "list.dash")
            }
    }
}

struct View2: View {
    var body: some View {
        Text("View 2")
            .customTabItem {
                Label("Order", systemImage: "square.and.pencil")
            }
    }
}
```

With this approach, the CustomView can read the size of the custom tab item used in its child elements and create a button or something else based on that information.

I hope this helps!

Comment: This code doesn't even work