# Identifiable Content views inside SwiftUI View

Tags: ios, swift, swiftui

My goal is to make a component that will be constructed as SwiftUI `List`. This component has two conditions: it accepts a group of views, and it allows you to select an item based on `Identifiable` protocol.

Pseudocode that visualise the case:

```swift
struct MainView: View {

private let list: [UUID] = [...]
@State private var selection: UUID?

var body: some View {
   PagingView($selection) {
      ForEach(list) {
         RowItemView(model: $0)
      }
   }
}
```

`PagingView` has initialiser that takes those two parameters:

```swift
struct PagingView<Content>: View where Content: View {

   private let content: Content
   @Binding private var selection: UUID?

   init(_ selection: Binding<UUID?>, @ViewBuiled content: @escaping () -> Content) { [...] }

   var body: some View {
      HStack {
         content
      }
   }
}
```

The case is that inside PagingView I want to make some calculations based on the view indexes and ids. Integer index is needed to calculate offset position but, as selection, I am passing id that is UUID.

**So the question is how to get information about subviews provided by the `ViewBuilder` closure?**

I had two solutions. First one replaced `Content` with `[Content]`:

```swift
struct PagingView<Content>: View where Content: View {

   private let content: [Content]
   @Binding private var selection: UUID?

   init(_ selection: Binding<UUID?>, @ViewBuiled content: @escaping () -> [Content]) { [...] }

   var body: some View {
      HStack {
         ForEach(content.enumerated()) { index, item in
            //save somewhere a pair of phisical Int index with Identifiable peoperty.
            store(item.id, for: index)

            return item
         }
      }
   }
}
```

Unfortunately, it does not work. This approach prevents `ForEach` from being used in the parent component. Actually, it solves the problem in a very narrow scope.

Second approach added additional `@Binding` to track `index` and `selection` simultaneously but then I have to synchronise those two values by `onChange` modifier.

Overall, I did not solve this problem for any particular case.

Comment: You can pass information from a view to its parent via [Preferences](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swiftui/preferences). A parent view can collect or reduce this information and take actions on changes.

Comment: @Sweeper yes. If some View has its model that conforms to `Identifiable` the id property should be fulfilled automatically.

Comment: @CouchDeveloper I will make a research if Preference could solve this problem.

Comment: If you want to collect the indices of the sub views, or the frames or other info available in a view,  in the parent view,  say in some `@State` variable (i.e. an array), then Preferences can do that.

Comment: This sounds like SwiftUI.Layout with the Layout replacing PagingView if it is only used for positioning

Comment: https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swiftui/composing_custom_layouts_with_swiftui

Comment: https://developer.apple.com/wwdc22/10056

Answer (score 0):

You can use the [View Extractor](https://github.com/GeorgeElsham/ViewExtractor) package to extract views out of a `ViewBuilder`. Do note that this uses underscore-prefixed (i.e. unstable) APIs.

Here is an example where tapping on the view changes the `selection` to the view's ID (assuming the ID is `UUID`).

```
struct PagingView<Content>: View where Content: View {
    
    private let content: Content
    @Binding private var selection: UUID?
    
    init(selection: Binding<UUID?>, @ViewBuilder content: () -> Content) {
        self.content = content()
        self._selection = selection
    }
    
    var body: some View {
        HStack {
            ExtractMulti(content) { views in
                ForEach(Array(views.enumerated()), id: \.element.id) { (i, view) in
                    // you can also use the index i here
                    view.onTapGesture {
                        selection = view.id(as: UUID.self)
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Example usage:

```
let list = [UUID(), UUID(), UUID()]

@State var selected: UUID?

var body: some View {
    VStack {
        PagingView(selection: $selected) {
            ForEach(list, id: \.self) {
                Text($0.uuidString)
                    // .id($0) // implicitly added by ForEach
            }
        }
        Text("Selected: \(selected?.uuidString ?? "Nothing")")
    }
}
```

See also [another use of View Extractor](https://stackoverflow.com/a/77758829/5133585).

Comment: I did not know this solution. Unfortunately, I am afraid that underscored types are not the best solution for production purpose. Maybe iOS 18 will bring something new in that case. ☺️