# How to create a custom picker?

Tags: swiftui, picker, viewbuilder

I am trying to create a custom `Picker` using a similar approach that Apple is taking. To put in simple terms I am trying to make the `Text` that is selected Blue and the `Text` that isn't selected Black.

So I got this far (see code below).

I have the feeling that I am close, but I am missing the last puzzle piece.

```
struct ContentView: View {
    @State private var selectionIndex: Int = 2

    var body: some View {
        CustomPicker(selection: $selectionIndex) {
            Text("1").tag(1)
            Text("2").tag(2)
        }
    }
}

struct CustomPicker<T: Hashable>: View {
    @Binding var selection: T
    
    init<Content: View>(selection: Binding<T>, @ViewBuilder content: () -> TupleView<(Content)>) {
        self._selection = selection
        let content = content() //<-- How to store content to be used in body?
    }

    init<each Content: View>(selection: Binding<T>, @ViewBuilder content: () -> TupleView<(repeat each Content)>) {
        self._selection = selection
        let content = content() //<-- How to store content to be used in body?
        
        repeat print(newView(each content.value)) //<-- How to create a new (altered) TupleView?
    }
    
    var body: some View {
        return Text("Done") //<-- Should return the altered content
    }
    
    func newView(_ view: some View) -> some View {
        if let tag = tag(view), tag == self.selection {
            return view.foregroundColor(.blue)
        } else {
            return view.foregroundColor(.black)
        }
    }
    
    func tag(_ view: some View) -> T? {
        Mirror(reflecting: view).descendant("modifier", "value", "tagged") as? T
    }
}

#Preview {
    ContentView()
}
```

Comment: See [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/77758829/5133585) for an example of how to extract the views in a view builder. You need to use unstable APIs for this. While it might be possible to use parameter packs, I think it would be very finicky - parameter packs often crash the compiler at the moment.

Comment: "make the `Text` that is selected Blue and the `Text` that isn't selected Black" is a bit too vague. How do you want the views to be arranged? Horizontally? Vertically? Should the picker show a pop-up with these `Text`s or is the picker inline? If you can show a mock up, I can write an answer.

Comment: Hi @Sweeper, thanks for responding. I wanted to keep it as minimal as possible. The Picker will wrap the children in separate buttons where a press on that button changes the selection. The buttons are arranged horizontally. It's nothing more than that.

Comment: Thanks for the example at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/78135638/swiftui-how-to-create-a-custom-picker?noredirect=1#comment137749934_78135638:~:text=See-,here,-for%20an%20example

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use [View Extractor](https://github.com/GeorgeElsham/ViewExtractor/tree/main) to get views out of a `ViewBuilder`. Do note that this uses unstable APIs.

Here is an example:

```
struct ContentView: View {
    @State private var selectionIndex: Int = 2
    
    var body: some View {
        CustomPicker(selection: $selectionIndex) {
            Text("1").id(1)
            Text("2").id(2)
            
        }
    }
}

struct CustomPicker<Content: View, Selection: Hashable>: View {
    let content: Content
    @Binding var selection: Selection
    
    init(selection: Binding<Selection>, @ViewBuilder content: () -> Content) {
        self.content = content()
        self._selection = selection
    }
    
    var body: some View {
        HStack {
            ExtractMulti(content) { views in
                ForEach(views) { view in
                    let tag = view.id(as: Selection.self)
                    Button {
                        if let tag {
                            selection = tag
                        }
                    } label: { view }
                        .foregroundStyle(selection == tag ? .blue : .black)
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Note that here I used `id` instead of `tag` to identify the view, because it is more convenient this way. The view trait key for `tag` is an internal type, so it is very difficult to access it. You can try and find a mirror path, but it might be easier to just write your own view trait key:

```
struct CustomTagTrait<V: Hashable>: _ViewTraitKey {
    static var defaultValue: V? { nil }
}

extension View {
    func customTag<V: Hashable>(_ tag: V) -> some View {
        _trait(CustomTagTrait<V>.self, tag)
    }
}

...

CustomPicker(selection: $selectionIndex) {
    Text("1").customTag(1)
    Text("2").customTag(2)
}
```

Then you can get the tag this way:

```
let tag = view[CustomTagTrait<Selection>.self]
```

Comment: I mark it as an answer because it is proper. It is to bad that there is a need for unstable API to accomplish something that feels so basic.

Comment: @Mark Hopefully we get a proper way to do this in the future :)