How SwiftUI's TabView Identify Each Item Internally?
When using a TabView:
TabView {
    ReceivedView()
        .badge(2)
        .tabItem {
            Label("Received", systemImage: "tray.and.arrow.down.fill")
        }
    SentView()
        .tabItem {
            Label("Sent", systemImage: "tray.and.arrow.up.fill")
        }
    AccountView()
        .badge("!")
        .tabItem {
            Label("Account", systemImage: "person.crop.circle.fill")
        }
}

However, I am wondering how TabView identify each view? I assume that internally, some code will be like
ForEach(Content.views) { view in
    if view == selectedItem {
        view
    }
}

But I don't know how to get the Content.views, any idea?

Are you trying to write your own tab view? See my answer here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/77758829/5133585

I'm guessing a little, but I believe it uses Tags via ViewTraitKey's and VariadicViews.
I'll attempt to replicate the selection behaviour below
First we will define a few things to help us out.

A View to allow us to iterate over the child views from a ViewBuilder content

struct VariadicViewReader<Source: View, Content: View>: View {
    var source: Source
    var content: (_VariadicView.Children) -> Content

    init(_ source: Source, @ViewBuilder content: @escaping (_VariadicView.Children) -> Content) {
        self.source = source
        self.content = content
    }

    var body: some View {
        _VariadicView.Tree(Root(content: content)) { source }
    }

    private struct Root: _VariadicView.MultiViewRoot {
        var content: (_VariadicView.Children) -> Content

        func body(children: _VariadicView.Children) -> some View {
            content(children)
        }
    }

}


A mechanism for tagging our views with an identifier

private struct CustomTagTraitKey: _ViewTraitKey {
    static var defaultValue: AnyHashable? = nil
}

extension _VariadicView_Children.Element {
    var customTag: AnyHashable? {
        self[CustomTagTraitKey.self]
    }

    func customTag<T: Hashable>(as: T.Type) -> T? {
        customTag as? T
    }
}

extension View {
    func customTag<V: Hashable>(_ tag: V) -> some View {
        _trait(CustomTagTraitKey.self, AnyHashable(tag))
    }
}


With the setup now in place we can create a CustomTabView
struct CustomTabView<SelectionValue, Content>: View where SelectionValue: Hashable> {

    @Binding var selection: SelectionValue
    let content: Content

    init(_ selection: Binding<SelectionValue>, @ViewBuilder content: () -> Content) {
        self._selection = selection
        self.content = content()
    }

    var body: some View {
        VariadicViewReader(content) { children in
             ForEach(children) child in
                  if let tag = child.customTag(as: SelectionValue.self), tag == selection {
                      child
                  }
             }
        }
    }

}

This would then be used like
CustomTabView($selectedTab) {
    View1().customTag(0)
    View2().customTag(1)
}


or
CustomTabView($selectedTab) {
    ForEach([0, 1], id: \.self) { num
        View1().customTag(num)
    }
}

Here's a relevant note from Apples docs

A ForEach automatically applies a default tag to each enumerated view using the id parameter of the corresponding element. If the element’s id parameter and the picker’s selection input have exactly the same type, you can omit the explicit tag modifier. To see examples that don’t require an explicit tag, see Picker.

With this in mind
TabView {
    ForEach([0, 1], id: \.self) { num
        View1()
    }
}

is the same as
TabView {
    ForEach([0, 1], id: \.self) { num
        View1().tag(num)
    }
}


_VariadicView and other views begin with _ are internal views?

Underscored API’s aren’t intended for public use. However these particular APIs hold little risk due to being marked @frozen

I have copied above code into Xcode, but there are some errors I can't solve.  See this screenshot. https://img2.imgtp.com/2024/04/14/bYUYJa4i.png

I’m writing this out from my phone so made a few mistakes . I’ve edited the answer to hopefully correct the errors from your screenshot.
